# emacs 24+ with built-in semantic-mode with python file

Tags: emacs, semantics, cedet

With emacs 24/25, whenever I enable 'semantic-mode' as long as there is a python file opened in a buffer, I will get following error

```
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

Often, the whole emacs freezes.

For emacs24/25, I googled around, I don't see any good tutorial on CEDET 2.0 settings. Anyone can provide more general guideline will be helpful.